# Mongoose $group (aggregation) not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I can't for the life of me workout why this is returning an empty array. I have mongoose v4.1.11 and when I run:

```
db.getCollection('stats').find({user_id:ObjectId('56410153ba86a1e8227f2781'), year: '2015-16'})
```

It returns 5 results.

```
Stats.aggregate([
            { $match: {user_id:'56410153ba86a1e8227f2781', year: '2015-16'}},
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: null,
                        started: {$sum: "$goals"}
                }
            }
        ], function (err, results) {
            console.info(results); //[] Empty array
        });
```

Am I doing this wrong? The documentation quite clearly says you can use `null` for the `_id`

**Stats model**

```
var Stats = new Schema({
    game_id : {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Games", default: null},
    user_id : {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Player", default: null},
    week : Number,
    leagueID : String,
    year: String,
    app : {type: Number, default: 1},
    mins : {type: Number, default: 90},
    goals :Number,
    goal_ids : [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Goals"}],
    assists :Number,
    benchUnused :Number,
    bench :Number,
    rating :Number,
    captain :Number,
    cleanSheet :Number,
    kitWash :Number,
    ownGoal :Number,
    oppoOwnGoal :Number,
    pen :Number,
    penCondeded :Number,
    penMissed :Number,
    penSaved:Number,
    motm:Number,
    redCard:Number,
    yellowCard:Number,
    secondYellowCard:Number,
    started:Number,
    subbedOff:Number,
    subbedOn:Number,
    pts:{type: Number, default: 0},
    venue:String
})

mongoose.model('Stats', Stats);
```

Comment: can you show us the `stats` document?

Comment: Are you sure `goals` is a valid field?

Comment: Please provide at least one sample document.

Comment: See update, I should have said I am sure that everything is correct

Comment: Mongoose does not "autocast" schema types in the aggregation pipeline. You need to cast `ObjectId` manually.

Comment: You don't say Blakes... Could you add that as the accepted answer please? Mongoose.Types.ObjectId... I missed that in the docs